# Firebase .childAdded producing duplicate outputs in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code to observe new comments for a pic and present the number of new comments of all pics overall:

```
    let ref4 = DatabaseReference.media.reference()
        let query4 = ref4.child("\(value)/comments")
        query4.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
         let comment = Comment(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
           self.myNotif.insert(comment, at: 0)

           self.newComment.text = ("\(self.myNotif.count)")
            print("new comment noticed")
```

the problem is that despite only adding one child to the database, the console is duplicating the results. There will be duplicate print statements for instance. The main issue with this is that it is also increasing the counter by 2 instead of one. Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: Please make sure your question contains enough information to troubleshoot what's going wrong. At the very least we'll need to see the JSON, which you can get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). But no counter is incremented in your code, so even with that it'll be incomplete. The best I can say at this point is that `.childAdded` fires for each child under the location that you observe.

Comment: I recommend reading up on [how to create a minimal, complete verifiable reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's by far the best way to get help with code here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am in total agreement with @FrankvanPuffelen. We would need to see your structure to gain an understanding of the data you are working with. Additionally he is also correct in there is no counter in the code presented so it's unclear how that's being incremented. Oh - can you include the code that writes out the node as well? We can take a look at that as perhaps there's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I added an extension to my comment class to include a conformity to Equitable protocol and then changed the completion to:

```
    if !self.myNotif.contains(comment) {
           self.myNotif.insert(comment, at: 0)

           self.newComment.text = ("\(self.myNotif.count)")
            print("new comment noticed")
            }
```

and it seems to fix the discrepancy

Comment: This doesn't really fix the actual issue - it more works around it. If the code in your original question (print) is being called twice, you may have duplicate data which is going to be an issue at some point.